# how to type a generator function in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have this code:

```js
export const runWithCancel = <R, TNext>(fn: Generator<unknown, R, TNext>) => {
  const gen = fn();
};
```

But I get

```
This expression is not callable.
  Type 'Generator<unknown, R, TNext>' has no call signatures.
```

How do I type a generator in typescript

Comment: From, [TypeScript 3.6 Stricter Generators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-6.html): "the new `Generator` type is an `Iterator` that always has both the `return` and `throw` methods present, and is also iterable." What are you expecting from an attempt to call it directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generator function is a function that will return a generator. In your case `runWithCancel` is expection a generator, not a generator function.

Try the following:

```
export const runWithCancel = <R, TNext>(fn: () => Generator<unknown, R, TNext>) => {
  const gen = fn();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

A `Generator` is a result of a `GeneratorFunction`. If `fn` is a function, then I think the type of `fn` will be `GeneratorFunction` and `gen` will be `Generator`:

```
export const runWithCancel = <R, TNext>(fn: GeneratorFunction) => {
  const gen = fn() as Generator<unknown, R, TNext>;
};
```